# Using strong mathematical induction to prove a statement

Tags: induction

So I have a question that I got stuck on, it says I have to prove that all integers greater than 17 can be written using a sum of 7's and 4's. For instance **7 + 7 + 7 + 4 + 4 = 29** or **7 + 4 + 4 + 4 = 19** .... etc. Appreciate the help. Cheers.

Comment: FYI, this is a specific case of the [coin problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem).

Comment: What have you done on it so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x$ has atleast one $7$, remove it and add two $4$'s. If $x$ has all $4$'s remove five $4$'s and add three $7$'s. (In the latter case $x \geq 20$ necessarily).

If you need to use strong induction, then we have for $x-4$ when $x \geq 22$, that $x$ satisfies the condition. Then the cases for $18,19,20,21$ are clear.

Comment: Yes, I have deduced this method, but I am just stuck on how should I explain it using strong Mathematical induction

Comment: I mean technically you can use strong induction without using the "strong" part of the hypothesis. I don't see how much that would add; it proves unnecessary here. Any strong induction argument you make will be reducible to this simple induction.